# Wordpress Menus and using :first-letter

Tags: css, wordpress

I am wanting to use `:first-letter` on the code below but I am unsure on the correct procedure or if possible can it be applied to `<li>`?

**Code:**

```
<div class="menu-left_menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-left_menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3632" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-3632"><a href='http://#.co.nz/new'>Home</a> : </li>
        <li id="menu-item-3705" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3705"><a href='http://#.co.nz/new/about-us/'>About Us</a> : </li>         
        <li id="menu-item-3702" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-3702"><a href='http://#.co.nz/new/shop/'>Shop</a> : </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this i think this is used full.

```
<div class="menu-left_menu-container">
<ul id="menu-left_menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-3632" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-3632"><a href='http://#.co.nz/new'>Home</a> : </li>
    <li id="menu-item-3705" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3705"><a href='http://#.co.nz/new/about-us/'>About Us</a> : </li>         
    <li id="menu-item-3702" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-3702"><a href='http://#.co.nz/new/shop/'>Shop</a> : </li>
</ul>
```

write css like this it is working.

```
#menu-left_menu > li::first-letter{
   color:red;
}
```

below css is not working. above css is working.

```
#menu-left_menu > li > a::first-letter{
   color:red;
}
```

According to the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-CSS2-20101207/selector.html#first-letter), the :first-letter pseudo-element only work for a block element, which `a` is not.